# Removing LI from UL in for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove items from a list when a button is clicked.

JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/y3u47f11/15/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn" onclick="emptyList()">clear list</a>
```

**JS**

```
window.emptyList = function () {
  var ul = document.querySelector('.list');
  var listLength = ul.children.length;

  for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    ul.childNodes[i].removeChild();
  }

  // this works
  // ul.innerHTML = "";

}
```

The problem is that when i click the button only a few items are removed from the list e.g. in the example above I click the 'clear list' button once and items 1, 3 and 5 are removed. I click the button a second time and item 2 is removed. Finally on the third click the list is emptied.

I can actually remove the elements easily enough if i set ul.innerHTML = "";

But I can't seem to figure out why the the emptyList function isn't working as expected and would appreciate any insight in to where i'm going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: what `ul.children.length` returns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`chlidren`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) or [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) is live [element collection(HTMLCollection)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) so index may update after each remove, so remove the element at index `0`. Although apply `removeChild` on parent node and add element as the argument.

```js
window.emptyList = function () {
  var ul = document.querySelector('.list');
  var listLength = ul.children.length;

  for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.children[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn" onclick="emptyList()">clear list</a>
```

---

**FYI :** The [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) includes the text nodes so use [`chlidren`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property instead.

Comment: Thanks Pranav for the solution and the explanation. That works great.

Also thanks everyone else for other answers.

Comment: @JonK :  glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do it in reverse order because when removing a node index no longer points to the correct node afterwards because the whole list has been reduced. Also, just query the li elements directly

```js
window.emptyList = function () {
  var li = document.querySelectorAll('.list > li');
  var listLength = li.length;
  
  for (var i = listLength-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    li[i].parentNode.removeChild(li[i]);   
  }
  
  // this works
  // ul.innerHTML = "";

}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn" onclick="emptyList()">clear list</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer too. A very useful alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. You are using `removeChild` wrong way.

```
window.emptyList = function () {
      var ul = document.querySelector('.list');
      var listLength = ul.children.length;

      for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.emptyList = function () {
  var ul = document.querySelector('.list');
  var listLength = ul.children.length;

  while (ul.children.length !=0){
    ul.removeChild(ul.childNodes[0]);
  }

  // this works
  // ul.innerHTML = "";

}
```

the list length is altered once you remove the first one.