# JavaScript issue on filtering text in html element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I've been struggling with the same piece of code for a few days by now...

So for the html part I have this :

```html
<input type="text" id="search_immobilier_ville" name="search_immobilier[ville]">
<div class="collection" id="search-ville-collection"></div>
```

I have an input where I have to type any city name, then I want to filter the matching cities names into an existing array of cities like this :

```
let api_results = [['Le Moule',97152],['Lamentin',97189],...]
let ville_input = document.getElementById('search_immobilier_ville');
```

Then display the matching cities as a list of elements in the div `#search-ville-collection`.

On each keyup event, I need to perform this action, and update the visual list in real time.

My issue is that my filtering system is messed up, if I search "lam" for example, I can get a city called "**lam**entin" (pass the test) and another with just the "la" matching like "capesterre-de-marie-ga**la**nte"

So far, I've done this :

```js
// Previously filled by an API
let api_results = [[name,postalCode],[name,postalCode],...];

ville_input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  let value = ville_input.value.toUpperCase().trim();

  // User input
  let input_val = ville_input.value.toUpperCase().trim();

  // Filtering through var ville_input
  api_results.forEach(el => {
    if (el[0].toUpperCase().startsWith(input_val) || input_val.length >= 2 && el[0].toUpperCase().includes(input_val)) {
      result_list.style.display = 'block';

      // if city not present in the html list, add it
      if (document.getElementById(el[1]) === null) {
        $(result_list).append(`<a class="collection-item search-ville-results" id="${el[1]}"> ${el[0]} - ${el[1]} </a>`);
      }
    }
  }); // End forEach

  /* Looping through the collection child nodes to check
    if there are cities that don't match the user input */
  for (let child of result_list.children) {
    console.log(child)

    // if the user input doesn't match with an existing city in the node, delete the node
    if (!child.text.toUpperCase().includes(input_val)) {
      result_list.removeChild(child);
    }
  }

  // Highlight first element of the list
  result_list.firstElementChild.classList.add('active');

  // empty results div if user input is empty
  if (input_val == '') {
    result_list.style.display = 'none';
    result_list.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

This code works PARTIALLY. For example, if I type "lam", I'm supposed to get only one result based on my result set, but check out this scenario :

#### Typing "l":

[image: Screenshot "l"]

#### Typing "la":

[image: Screenshot "la"]

#### Typing "lam":

[image: Screenshot "lam"]

(Here you begin to see the issue)

#### Typing "lame":

[image: Screenshot "lame"]

I'm sure there's something wrong in my code, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing LI from UL in for loop (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853028/removing-li-from-ul-in-for-loop-js), even though you're not using `li`, the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the loop you are using to remove invalid items:

```
for (let child of result_list.children) {
  console.log(child)

  // if the user input doesn't match with an existing city in the node, delete the node
  if (!child.text.toUpperCase().includes(input_val)) {
    result_list.removeChild(child);
  }
}
```

[`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) returns a live `HTMLCollection`, meaning that if you modify it (eg, by removing items) it will update, which will cause issues with your loop. You need to go through the items in a way that will not be affected if the collection changes.

**Wrong way:**

This is an example of how the loop behaves currently. The button should remove all the items that contain "th", but note how it doesn't get them all and requires multiple clicks:

```js
document.querySelector('#removeAll').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('#list')
  for (let item of list.children) {
    if (item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes('th')) {
      list.removeChild(item)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="removeAll">Remove All</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Things</li>
  <li>Others</li>
  <li>More</li>
</ul>
```

**(A) correct way:**

One way to loop through the collection in a way that is not affected by items being removed is to start at the last index and go backwards:

```js
document.querySelector('#removeAll').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('#list')
  let index = list.children.length
  while (index--) {
    let item = list.children[index]
    if (item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes('th')) {
      list.removeChild(item)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="removeAll">Remove All</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Things</li>
  <li>Others</li>
  <li>More</li>
</ul>
```

**Better way**

As an additional note, you might be better off just clearing the list entirely and using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the matching results and then update the list that way. As it is currently, you are doing a lot of checking to see if the list already contains the item, checking the current list for invalid items, etc. That will affect performance of your UI, especially on lower end devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear out your `result_list` as the first thing you do inside your `keyup` event.

```
result_list.innerHTML = '';
```

After that, make sure to filter your `api_results`.

```
const filteredResults = api_results.filter(result => result[0].toUpperCase().includes(input_val));
console.log(filteredResults); // Sanity check.
filteredResults.forEach(result => /* your old function. */);
```

Comment: I thought at first that emptying the html list would negatively affect the UI performances, but actually that happens super fast, so good idea, thanks !